# web.config error in compilation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compilation, web-config

In MVC .net Framework 4.5, I make a JQuery Ajax POST call to partial view action method.

But Instead, it redirects to an action which I is a route on the top of the RouteConfig file:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

It gives this error:
"public method was not found on controller"
in this line of code:

```
 Html.RenderAction("GetRate", "Exchange", new { area = "ExchangeArea" });
```

In Global.asax

> Error executing child request for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.'

I continued to see the actual error, it is:

*Parser Error Message*:

> Unrecognized element 'compilation'.

*Source Error*:

> ```
> <customErrors mode="Off" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
> Line 89:      <compilation debug="true"/>
> Line 90:   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/HTML404.cshtml"/>
> Line 91: </customErrors>
> ```

Comment: Seems odd. If that line were incorrect in the config or in the wrong place you would get an error message about not being able to debug. What error is returned if you capture Server.GetLastError();  in Application_Error in the Global.asax?

Comment: @Wheels73 I updated my question. The problem is, It redirects to a partial view  which is my default view in RouteConfig. and gives error while rendering that view.. This is weird..

Comment: Do you have [HttpGet] decorated above your controller action for GetRate\Exchange?

Comment: @Wheels73 Yes I have

Comment: Ok.. remove it and see what happens!

Comment: @Wheels73 Wow yes It worked Thank you!

Comment: @Wheels73 The error disappeared but it still should not redirect to this action view. Because I am not calling it. Do you have idea about it?

Comment: Cool. Can I get an upvote if  i post an answer?  Basically because your are doing a Post from Ajax, it can't find the action as it's got a get on it.

Comment: Will try,...be back in 30 mins though.

Comment: @Wheels73 Sure. So this means it can't find the ajax call method and redirects to default view from RouteConfig?

Comment: @Wheels73 I found now, It is because I use input type="submit" to call ajax. Submit refreshes the page, and calls that view. Changed it to button type and now its ok.

Comment: Excellent.. I'll post my 1st answer then.. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, please remove the HttpGet attribute from your controllers action that the ajax post calls.